# Populating ListView using ArrayAdapter,application stopped

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Hi all I am newbie to android programming. I am trying to populate ListView through Array Adapter. After run the error is : Unfortunately App is stopped .I don't know what is going wrong.I trieed running the code without setAdapter and It worked fine. Here is my Code

Layout File : 
1. activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/emp_name"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/emp_name" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_search"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="search" />
   </LinearLayout>

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/emp_list"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

2.emp_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/emp_item"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>
```

1. Main_activity.java

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       String[] employees = {"Christophe Coenraets", "John Smith"};

       ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.emp_item,employees);     

       ListView employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.emp_list);
       employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

   }
   ```

Comment: Here is the start of the log:    D/dalvikvm(786): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77K, 9% free 2546K/2772K, paused 71ms, total 77ms
 D/AndroidRuntime(786): Shutting down VM
07-24 23:09:11.386: W/dalvikvm(786): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-24 23:09:11.415: E/AndroidRuntime(786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 23:09:11.415: E/AndroidRuntime(786): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080002 type #0x12 is not valid
07-24 23:09:11.415: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2144)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the content view first as shown in the following code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   String[] employees = {"Christophe Coenraets", "John Smith"};

   ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.emp_item,employees);

   ListView employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.emp_list);
   employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In your case, it returns null on findViewById(R.id.emp_list) because its content view is not specified yet.

Answer (score 0):

setContentView must be used first...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
String[] employees = {"Christophe Coenraets", "John Smith"};

ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.emp_item,employees);

ListView employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.emp_list);
employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: In the log I found Invalid Resource ID : 00079x which in R.java points to emp_item Textview, Apparently the text view was declared in emp_list_item.xml file. I created text view in activity_main file and referred it in adapter. Now the application didn't gave any error but it is without any output.

Comment: "without any output." Do you mean your list isn't being populated? Or the entire screen is blank, and doesn't even show your `edittext` and button?

Comment: Yes the entire screen blank. After changing the textview: log says 07-24 23:33:21.545: E/Trace(854): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)